# Can I clear the Managed Object Context?

Tags: iphone, core-data

Problem: I am doing a really big import where I parse an XML file. For every 10 parsed managed objects, I want to save the Managed Object Context and get rid of those 10 objects in memory, so that I have never more than 10 objects in memory at a time.

After saving it, how could I clear the context so that all the objects go away from memory?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In a situation like this there are four things to remember to do:

1. Wrap your loop in a `NSAutoreleasePool`
2. Periodically save the context; then
3. Reset the context with -reset
4. Release and re-create the autorelease pool

This will flush all of the memory being used and clear the context.

Comment: Hey Marcus!! Aren't you the guy who wrote that big Core Data book? Thanks for the answer. Pretty sure it's the best one ;)

Comment: I think we've encountered some problems these instructions don't work for. I'd love to find out different. SO User http://stackoverflow.com/users/1949877/scott-carter has a blog post http://finalize.com/2013/01/04/core-data-issues-with-memory-allocation/. Our problems are identical to the `NSTemporaryObjectID_default` section. Also cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575994.

Comment: The example that Scott Carter is working with in his test is poor due to use `UIManagedDocument`. `UIManagedDocument` uses a multi-moc design and releasing memory in that case is quite a bit more complicated than the straight forward situation discussed in this question.  If memory management and control over the release of memory is a concern I would not use `UIManagedDocument`. In truth, I would not use it for any reason at this time as it has many documented issues. I would suggest opening a new question and sending me the link so we can work on it together.