# Multiple instances of _CDSnapshot_[entityName]_

Tags: iphone, core-data

I am seeing thousands of instances of *CDSnapshot*[entityName]_ when using 'instruments' to track unreferenced allocations.

What is this? I presume it is CoreData related?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is related to Core Data and I believe is to be expected.

See my reply at:

[Setter for NSManagedObject creates _CDSnapshot_Provence_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979085/setter-for-nsmanagedobject-creates-cdsnapshot-provence)

and a blog post I wrote which discusses this (and other Core Data issues) at:

http://finalize.com/2013/01/04/core-data-issues-with-memory-allocation/

Scott